# why when I try the Pull Request to GitHub is not complete?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

I am try to send a Pull Request to my GitHub repository, to branch `master` in Visual Studio Code. I create my issue, go to command-promt and choose option "Create Pull Request for #1" but the process never complete.

[image]

I don't see any log error or how to resolve it

[image]

i expected like this:

Comment: Which parameters are being used when creating this pull request? What're you expecting to happen?

Comment: i mentioned:i go to command-promt and choose option "Create Pull Request for #1"   then notification is begin "start creating pull request" like the picture

Comment: @zrrbite you can see this video for details: http://srecorder.com/s/a8qy

Comment: Are there any logs for that plugin so you can see if something went wrong?

Comment: no there aren´t

Answer (score 1):

You might need, after initiating the PR creation process, to select a commit or branch as shown in the popup menu at the top of the screen.

Once you have selected the commit or branch from which you want to initiate the PR, said pull-request can then be created.

Comment: it´s ok @VonC, i suppose it was not necesary. thanks very much